# Image thresholding not working on Laplacian image

Tags: python, image-processing, threshold, laplacian

I need to perform a thresholded zero-crossing detection of the filtered image's laplacian. But once the laplacian is applied, it gives error when doing thresholding. Any advice?

**code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('H:/FYP/interim/aniso.jpg')
lap = cv2.Laplacian(img, 1, ksize=5)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(lap, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(threshold)
```

**error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e36300501b24> in <module>
      1 img = cv2.imread('H:/FYP/interim/aniso.jpg')
      2 lap = cv2.Laplacian(img, 1, ksize=5)
----> 3 retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(lap, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
      4 plt.imshow(threshold)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1612: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::threshold'
```

Comment: You need to specify your desired ddepth. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6. The laplacian typically produces a floating point image -1 to 1. So you need to scale the image back to 8-bit 0 to 255 range. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html. Here is a link to zero crossing. https://theailearner.com/tag/cv2-laplacian/ You should always refer to the OpenCV documentation and/or search Google (and this forum) first, when you have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can change like this

```
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```